# Is it possible to customise the visible edges of a matplotlib table cell while also setting a background colour?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to overlay a matplotlib table on a plot that has a grid, i.e. the table should hide anything behind it on the grid.

I would also like the border to look more like each row has the border rather than a border around each cell. However setting `cell.visible_edges` seems to break the fill.

An example to illustrate

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# a plot with a grid
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
y = x ** 2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()

# a table on the same axis with a visible background colour
col_labels = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
row_labels = ['row1', 'row2', 'row3']
table_vals = [[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33, ]]
colours = [['c'] * 3] * 3

the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
                      colWidths=[0.1] * len(col_labels),
                      cellColours=colours,
                      rowLabels=row_labels,
                      bbox=(0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2))

# bump the zorder up so it occludes the underlying chart
the_table.set_zorder(1000)

# change the visible_edges to produce a row border effect
for row_idx, row in enumerate(table_vals):
    for col_idx, col in enumerate(row):
        edges = 'B'
        if col_idx == 0:
            edges += 'L'
        elif col_idx == 2:
            edges += 'R'
        the_table[row_idx, col_idx].visible_edges = edges

plt.show()
```

The result is that cells are filled inconsistently and the grid is still visible

[image: bad fill]

If I remove the change to visible_edges then it fills as expected

[image: good fill]

Is there a way to combine these two effects?

(examples created using matplotlib 2.2.3)

Comment: Your code works fine for me even without the last two for loops but keeping the `the_table.set_zorder(1000)` on `2.2.2`

Comment: There is no straight forward solution to this. The best you can do is probably to not fill the cells at all and produce a Rectangle in the desired color behind the table.

Comment: the problem is that invisible edges are [not part of the path](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/85c9742b5a4ab96afeb8257cc50cf0b29669f6ad/lib/matplotlib/table.py#L192). To solve this one would need make the `Cell` class consist of two shapes, one for the lines and one for the edges.